# MYSQL - Query para trazer os planos e cursos mais vendidos, com groupby diferente

Tags: mysql

Eu vendo assinaturas do meu curso online, e também os cursos de forma avulsa.

Gostaria de trazer o **top 5** de planos/cursos mais vendidos. Para isso, disponho de uma tabela chamada `subscriptionPlan`, que guarda o *id* do plano comprado, ou no caso de um curso, o *id* deste, e o valor gasto nesta transação. Exemplo:

Tabela `subscriptionPlan`:

```
sbpId | subId | plaId | couId | sbpAmount
1     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 499.99
2     | 2     | 1     | 2     | 499.99
3     | 3     | 2     | 0     | 899.99
4     | 4     | 1     | 1     | 499.99
```

Só pra fins didáticos, `plaId = 1` é um plano chamado **Venda avulsa** que criei, pra manter a integridade do banco. Quando tem um *couId* preenchido, quer dizer também que foi comprado um curso avulso, e nao um plano onde podem assistir qualquer curso.

Reitero a minha necessidade: Listar o top 5 de vendas. Caso seja um plano, exibir o nome do plano (tabela *plan*, coluna *plaTitle*). Caso seja um curso, exibir o nome deste (tabela *course*, coluna *couTitle*). Esta lógica que não estou conseguindo montar.

Eu consegui montar um top 5 de PLANOS, mas ele agrupa os cursos, já que o `GROUP BY` está pelo ID do plano. Acredito que a jogada esteja aqui, criar um `IF/ELSE` neste `GROUPBY`, mas aí não sei o que fazer.

A consulta que criei, que agrupa os planos é esta:

```
SELECT sp.plaId, sp.couId, p.plaTitle, p.plaPermanent, c.couTitle, SUM(sbpAmount) AS sbpTotalAmount
FROM subscriptionPlan sp
LEFT JOIN plan p ON sp.plaId = p.plaId
LEFT JOIN course c ON sp.couId = c.couId
GROUP BY sp.plaId
ORDER BY sbpTotalAmount DESC
LIMIT 5
```

O resultado que preciso seria:

```
plaId | couId | plaTitle        | couTitle   | plaPermanent | sbpTotalAmount
1     | 1     | Venda avulsa    | Curso 01   | true         | 999.98
2     | 0     | Acesso total    | null       | false        | 899.99
1     | 2     | Venda avulsa    | Curso 02   | true         | 499.99
```

Como eu poderia chegar nesta fórmula?

Comment: Se na sua tabela `subscriptionPlan` existe as colunas `plaID`e `couID` referentes ao plano e curso, respectivamente, como você vai identificar se foi um curso ou um plano inscrito?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem essa modelagem da tabela *subscriptionPlan*, é possível comprar apenas um curso ou apenas um plano?

Comment: @AndréFilipe Você pode adquirir um plano (para assistir todos os cursos), ou um curso avulso. Quando a compra é de um curso avulso, atribuo o plaId = 1 (que é um plano que se chama Compra Avulsa). Logo, se couId for diferente de zero, quer dizer também que foi uma compra avulsa, mesmo que tenha plano preenchido.